# Edit github gist through Python with pyGithub lib

Tags: python-3.x, github, gist, pygithub

this is my first question to stackoverflow. So be kind, if I am not on topic or precise and help me improve for the next time.

I am trying to modify and existing Github Gist through Python3 using pyGithub.
I created an API-token and authentification works ok, but I am struggeling to edit the Gist. I could not find an appropriate example, that made it clear to me.

Here is my code:

```
from github import Github
g = Github("XXX")

test2 = {"description": "the description for this gist",
         "files": {"filter": {"content": "updated file contents"},
                   "Task": {"filename": "new_name.txt",
                   "content": "modified content"},
"new_file.txt": {
  "content": "a new file"
}
}
}

g.get_gist(id="b2c5668fefe1f2e80252aabf4ef4e96c").edit(test2)
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gist.py", line 15, in <module>
g.get_gist(id="b2c5668fefe1f2e80252aabf4ef4e96c").edit(test2)
  File "/Users/DSpreitz/ogn-silentwings/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/github/Gist.py", line 249, in edit
  assert description is github.GithubObject.NotSet or isinstance(description, str), description
AssertionError: {'description': 'the description for this gist', 'files': {'filter': {'content': 'updated file contents'}}}
```

I found some description of the pygithub lib here:
[pyGithub Docu](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#edit-a-gist)

This is the Gist I am trying to modify: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dspreitz/b2c5668fefe1f2e80252aabf4ef4e96c#file-filter)

Any help to solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

Dominic

Comment: The assertion error you got is a clue : the ``description`` parameter received by ``Gist.edit`` must be ``NotSet`` or a string, and it's a dictionary (with a "description" key, which is confusing). This is a general pattern in PyGithub : argument types are asserted before calling the GitHub  API.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with this code is that it's passing a dictionary to `Gist.edit`. `Gist.edit` accepts keyword arguments.

[PyGithub's documentation](http://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Gist.html#github.Gist.Gist.edit) says:

> edit(description=NotSet, files=NotSet)

so it should be called as `g.edit(description="new description", files=...)`. Regarding `files`, the same documentation says:

> files – dict of string to github.InputFileContent.InputFileContent

so the `files` parameter could look like:

```
{"foo.txt": github.InputFileContent(content="bar")}
```

Summarized:

```
import github

token = "..."  # https://github.com/settings/tokens

gh = github.Github(token)
gist = gh.get_gist("f04c4b19919c750602f4d0c5f7feacbf")
gist.edit(
    description="new description",
    files={"foo.txt": github.InputFileContent(content="bar")},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If using pyGithub lib is NOT a hard constraint then I'd suggest using [gifc](https://github.com/armsp/gifc) gist client also written in python. So for your case, editing or updating the gist can be done as follows after installing it via pip (after cloning) -

#### **Update a gist**

- **Edit all (or some) files iteratively**

  - `gifc update ffd2f4a482684f56bf33c8726cc6ae63 -i vi`
    You can get the *gist id* from the `get` method from earlier
- **Change description**

  - `gifc update ffd2f4a482684f56bf33c8726cc6ae63 -cd "New description"`
    You can get the *gist id* from the `get` method from earlier
- **Edit contents of a file interactively in an editor like *nano*, *vim* or *gedit***

  - `gifc update ffd2f4a482684f56bf33c8726cc6ae63 -f file_to_update.md`
- **Do both**

  - `gifc update ffd2f4a482684f56bf33c8726cc6ae63 -f file_to_update.md -cd "New description"`